# Problems with floated nav

Tags: html, css, web

I am having some problems with floated nav. As can be seen in the first image below, I use `position` in my code and the result is that the nav is floated above the logo when I scaled the browser.

But I want the nav and the logo to be separated (like the second image) whenever I scale the browser. What should I do?

Are there any other ways to do that without using float?

[image]

[image]

This my my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            max-width: 1600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        header{
            background-color: lightgray;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        header .logo{
            float: left;
        }

        header nav{
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
        }

        header li{
            float: left;
            margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }
        
        header a{
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: reduce the font size? and set `max-width` for `header nav`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Here's one:

Add this to your style:

```
nav {margin-left: 50px;}
```

Comment: The result still remains the same :(

Comment: @DunDev you can increase the margin, perhaps 100px. I don't have your icon photo so the margin might be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is one method using `float`:

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

header .logo{
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 35px;  
}

header li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

header a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1169px){
header .logo {
  width: 19%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
header .logo {
  width: 15%;
}
header a { 
  padding: 5px; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
header nav { 
  margin-top: 15px;  
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x183/000/fff&text=logo" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why two answers?

Comment: First I have done by float and second one done by flex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version where nav floats right: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hmuvcns/7/)

CSS:

```
        .wrapper{
            max-width: 1600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        header{
            background-color: lightgray;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        header .logo{
            float: left;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
  /* width is set to 80% and nav floats right, no pos absolute */
        header nav{
            float: right;
            width: 80%;
        }

        header li{
            float: left;
            margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        header a{
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: No problem :). If any of the answers helped, please check mark or up vote them

Answer (score 0):

This is other method using `display:flex`.

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
header li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

header a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
 .logo {
  width: 20%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x150/000/fff&text=logo" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust the widths a little bit. You can add `max-width` and `min-with` to both your logo and nav too.

```css
.wrapper{
                max-width: 1600px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            header{
                background-color: lightgray;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 20px;
                position: relative;
            }
/* add the width and margin to your logo class*/
            header .logo{
                float: left;
                margin-right:2%;
                width:26%;
            }
/* make sure your image has a width */
            header .logo img{
                width:100%;
            }
            
/* add the width to your nav class */
            header nav{
                float: right;
                width:70%;
                padding-top:5%;
            }

            header li{
                float: left;
                margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
            }

            header a{
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x183/000/fff&text=logo" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```